# Ajax Code that loads images on click next and previous for any kind of image silder that has huge no of Images using jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have one slider that works perfectly ..... but the images are loaded at the time of page load ...
I want to load the images on click because   I have lot of images to display so I can't load it my homepage because the page takes time to load so  I have to use Ajax that loads one image
and and append it to my list

can any body help me how to do it ...

here is the code .. its working ..

**the java script part**

```
(function($){
$.fn.imageSlider = function(options) {
    var options = $.extend({
        leftBtn: '.leftBtn',
        rightBtn: '.rightBtn',
        visible: 3,
        autoPlay: false,  // true or false
        autoPlayDelay: 10  // delay in seconds
    }, options);
    var make = function() {
        $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');

        var thisWidth = $(this).width();
        var mod = thisWidth % options.visible;
        if (mod) {
            $(this).width(thisWidth - mod); // to prevent bugs while scrolling to the end of slider
        }

        var el = $(this).children('ul');
        el.css({
            position: 'relative',
            left: '0'
        });
        var leftBtn = $(options.leftBtn), rightBtn = $(options.rightBtn);

        var sliderFirst = el.children('li').slice(0, options.visible);
        var tmp = '';
        sliderFirst.each(function(){
            tmp = tmp + '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
        });
        sliderFirst = tmp;
        var sliderLast = el.children('li').slice(-options.visible);
        tmp = '';
        sliderLast.each(function(){
            tmp = tmp + '<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>';
        });
        sliderLast = tmp;

        var elRealQuant = el.children('li').length;
        el.append(sliderFirst);
        el.prepend(sliderLast);
        var elWidth = el.width()/options.visible;
        el.children('li').css({
            float: 'left',
            width: elWidth
        });
        var elQuant = el.children('li').length;
        el.width(elWidth * elQuant);
        el.css('left', '-' + elWidth * options.visible + 'px');

        function disableButtons() {
            leftBtn.addClass('inactive');
            rightBtn.addClass('inactive');
        }
        function enableButtons() {
            leftBtn.removeClass('inactive');
            rightBtn.removeClass('inactive');
        }

        leftBtn.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
                disableButtons();
                el.animate({left: '+=' + elWidth + 'px'}, 400,
                    function(){
                        if ($(this).css('left') == '0px') {$(this).css('left', '-' + elWidth * elRealQuant + 'px');}
                        enableButtons();
                    }
                );
            }
            return false;
        });

        rightBtn.click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            if (!$(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
                disableButtons();
                el.animate({left: '-=' + elWidth  + 'px'}, 400,
                    function(){
                        if ($(this).css('left') == '-' + (elWidth * (options.visible + elRealQuant)) + 'px') {$(this).css('left', '-' + elWidth * options.visible + 'px');}
                        enableButtons();
                    }
                );
            }
            return false;
        });

        if (options.autoPlay) {
            function aPlay() {
                rightBtn.click();
                delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
            }
            var delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
            el.hover(
                function() {
                    clearTimeout(delId);
                },
                function() {
                    delId = setTimeout(aPlay, options.autoPlayDelay * 1000);
                }
            );
        }
    };
    return this.each(make);
};
```

})(jQuery);

**here is the html**

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
    <div class="slider">
    <ul id="imgList" class="sliderList">
    <li><img><src></li>
    <li><img><src></li>
    <li><img><src></li>
    <li><img><src></li>
    <li><img><src></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:nextImg();" class="slider-arrow sa-left"><img src="/evfimages/prevLogo.png"/></a>
    <a href="javascript:prevImg();" class="slider-arrow sa-right"><img src="/evfimages/nextLogo.png"/></a>
```

**This is the function that call Js File .**

```
jQuery('.slider').imageSlider({
        leftBtn: '.sa-left',
        rightBtn: '.sa-right',
        visible: 5,
    });
```

**And some CSS for formatting**

So I  have a large no of Images 500 .... so i want to use ajax that loads images on click and append to the current list of images ......

any link or suggestion will be appreciated ......

Comment: We don't know which kind of slider you use. Which events you hook to load the images. Could you showcase a bit of your sourcecode or the website url?

Comment: 1. post some code.
2. Send a list of images+urls, and the index of current image, and on click load the next/prev one...

Comment: can any one help me or give some code for demo .....